# In Python 2.7, isn't it better to call the Super Constructor via super(self.__class__, self)...?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, inheritance, super

To call the constructor of a parent class in Python 2.7, the standard code that I've seen is:

`super(Child, self).__init__(self, val)`,

where `Child` is the child class. (In Python 3.x, this is simplified, but I have to use 2.7 for now.) My question is, wouldn't it be better for the "canonical" use of super in python 2.7 to be:

`super(self.__class__, self).__init__(self, val)`?

I've tested this, and it seems to work. Is there any reason not to use this approach?

Comment: Check what happens when you inherit from your class.

Comment: If it were as simple as passing `self.__class__`, `super` wouldn't have been designed to require that argument in the first place.

Comment: You would then refer to the next class up the chain, rather than the one you originally intended. Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Python 3.x, this is simplified, but I have to use 2.7 for now.

A better way to call the super constructor in Python 2.7 is using [Python-Future](http://python-future.org/overview.html#code-examples). It allows to use the Python 3 `super()` in Python 2 with:

```
from builtins import super  # from Python-Future

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hello')

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


Child()
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Bleh. It's convenient, sure, but looking at [the code behind the magic](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/fe494df5d66db19af94a1fdc32afe0e2e52dcf66/src/future/builtins/newsuper.py), it looks really slow and prone to weird failures if you do something like `__hash__ = Parent.__hash__`, since it assumes that the method is only present in the dict of one class in the MRO.

Answer (score 4):

This construct causes `RecursionError` when class is subclassed.

MCVE:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()


class B(A):
    pass

B()
```